# PySpark feature selection and interpretability

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Is there a way in PySpark to perform feature selection, but preserve or obtain a mapping back to the original feature indices/descriptions?

For example:

1. I have a StringArray column of raw feature strings (col =
   "rawFeatures").
2. I've converted them to numerical counts using
   `CountVectorizer` (col = "features").
3. Then I've run the `ChiSqSelector`
   to select the top 1000 features (col = "selectedFeatures).

How do I get the raw feature strings that correspond to those top 1000 features (or even just the corresponding indices of these selected features in the original "features" col from step #2)?

Answer (score 6):

This information can be traced back using `fitted` `Transformers`. With `Pipeline` like this one:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
import numpy as np

data = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, ["spark", "foo", "bar"]), (0, ["kafka", "bar", "foo"])],
    ("label", "rawFeatures"))

model = Pipeline(stages = [
    CountVectorizer(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features"),
    ChiSqSelector(outputCol="selectedFeatures", numTopFeatures=2)
]).fit(data)
```

you can extract `Transformers`:

```py
vectorizer, chisq = model.stages
```

and compare `selectedFeatures` with `vocabulary`:

```py
np.array(vectorizer.vocabulary)[chisq.selectedFeatures]
```

```
array(['spark', 'kafka'], dtype='<U5')
```

Unfortunately this combination of `Transformers` doesn't preserve labels metadata:

```py
features_meta, selected_features_meta = (f.metadata for f in model
    .transform(data).select("features", "selectedFeatures")
    .schema
    .fields)

features_meta
```

```
{}
```

```py
selected_features_meta
```

```
{'ml_attr': {'attrs': {'nominal': [{'idx': 0}, {'idx': 1}]}, 'num_attrs': 2}}
```